# Touchpad and mouse get stuck on virtualbox windows10-guest

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed virtualbox on macos and I need to host a windows10. I have two problem with this. First, however I allocate enough RAM and CPU to my windows-guest, it is kind of slow. Second, the touchpad or mouse does not work correctly in most of times and it make me restart the windows. It stays in click-condition and there is no way for me to release the click. So, is there anyway to fix them?

Comment: Install the VirtualBox Additions, this will allow your mouse to pass between.  Define slow...running 2 OSes on one computer will have some effect on the overall speed.  Also, you need to balance what you allocate, too many resources (both CPU and RAM) to the VM will negatively affect both host and VM performance.

Comment: If the VirtualBox Additions are not installed you have to press a special key to release the focus from a virtual machine. On PCs this is usually the right Ctrl key. Not sure what key it is by default of MacOS.